# how to traverse a entire domain instead of providing individual links

Tags: python, scrapy

Currently our spider works off a list of hard coded urls, would like to change that to just work off the main domain.

How can we change the below code to just expect the domain

```
https://www.example.com/shop/
```

If there is a good source with examples that would be great.

```
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
#                'https://www.example.com/shop/outdoors-unknown-hart-creek-fleece-hoodie',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/adidas-unknown-essentials-cotton-fleece-3s-over-head-hoodie#repChildCatSku=111767466',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/unknown-metallic-long-sleeve-shirt#repChildCatSku=115673740',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/unknown-fleece-full-zip-hoodie#repChildCatSku=111121673',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/unknown-therma-fleece-training-hoodie#repChildCatSku=114784077',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/under-unknown-rival-fleece-crew-sweater#repChildCatSku=114636980',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/unknown-element-1-2-zip-top#repChildCatSku=114794996',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/unknown-element-1-2-zip-top#repChildCatSku=114794996',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/under-unknown-rival-fleece-full-zip-hoodie#repChildCatSku=115448841',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/under-unknown-rival-fleece-crew-sweater#repChildCatSku=114636980',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/adidas-unknown-essentials-3-stripe-fleece-sweatshirt#repChildCatSku=115001812',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/under-unknown-fleece-logo-hoodie#repChildCatSku=115305875',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/under-unknown-heatgear-long-sleeve-shirt#repChildCatSku=107534192',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/unknown-long-sleeve-legend-hoodie#repChildCatSku=112187421',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/unknown-element-1-2-zip-top#repChildCatSku=114794996',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/unknown-sportswear-funnel-neck-hoodie-111112208#repChildCatSku=111112208',
                'https://www.example.com/shop/unknown-therma-swoosh-fleece-training-hoodie#repChildCatSku=114784481',
            ]
        for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
            page = response.url.split("/")[-1]
            filename = 'academy-%s.txt' % page
            res2 = response.xpath("//span[@itemprop='price']/text()|//span[@itemprop='sku']/text()").extract()             

            res = '\n'.join(res2)

            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                    f.write(res)
                    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for pure traversing you can make:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/shop/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('a'):
            yield response.follow(link)
```

But this task seems meaningless. Can you detail your question?

Comment: So we have been tasked to work on a crawler for our internal site.. Mostly i think its just to get an idea if we can accomplish it in house. Either way, currently the above code logic works great, it parses out the individual links/pages and returns just the 2 bits of data we want on those pages.  But the above is merely a quick sample for them to see that we can grab some specific data out of the pages..  The issue/question now is if we can make it a little easier by means of just providing our domain name and root folder in this case the "shop" folder and let the spider crawl anything under

Comment: I ran my code above and works, but the only thing i noticed is that even though i provide the start URL, its going outside that URL and crawling the rest of the site.. how can i make sure that it only traverses under the start URL and nothing outside of that?